# Getting - "Failed to parse StatusCallback URL per RFC2396" while trying to receive a response from twilio

Tags: c#, .net, url, post, twilio

I am currently developing an SMS service in my .NET application for which I have used Twilio and ServiceStack.

I am able to send an SMS to the destination number successfully, and with that I am also passing a callback URL on which I am expecting a response from Twilio.

However, when I checked the Twilio logs, it always says:

```
Failed to parse StatusCallback URL per RFC2396
```

And so the callback doesn't take place.
I have set following URL as a Callback URL:

> http://98erggkk.ngrok.io/json/oneway/TwilioCallBack?ServiceAuthKey=6j4%7C59%7CV

I have encoded the query parameter in the URL using (`Uri.EscapeUriString`), but it doesn't matter, as it doesn't work if I don't escape it.

Twilio is expected to POST the response at the same URL.

I can see the URL getting hit if I simply copy-paste this link to browser.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Can you drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com with a message sid for a message that failed like this? I'll take a look into the back.

Comment: @philnash - I have sent you an email with the Message Sid, and also, as mentioned in the email, I observed that this happens only for specific special characters in the query string. In my case, Pipe ("|") is one of the value in the query string, and I have also encoded before setting the callback URL.

Comment: @philnash - did you get a chance to look into why pipe character doesn't work with query string during Twilio callbacks? Thanks